# What do three dots mean in a designated initializer?

Tags: c, gcc, designated-initializer

I found this in
[`linux/include/linux/cpumask.h`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/cpumask.h#L780):

```
#define CPU_BITS_ALL                        \
{                               \
    [0 ... BITS_TO_LONGS(NR_CPUS)-2] = ~0UL,        \
    [BITS_TO_LONGS(NR_CPUS)-1] = CPU_MASK_LAST_WORD     \
}
#endif /* NR_CPUS > BITS_PER_LONG */
```

What do the three dots (`...`) mean? I am assuming the three dots transform the
line into something such as this:

```
[0] = ~0UL,     \
[1] = ~0UL,     \
[n] = ~0UL,     \
...
[BITS_TO_LONGS(NR_CPUS)-2] = ~0UL,      \
```

But I am uncertain. I was unable to find an answer to my question through
Google. The three dots may be part of a GCC extension to C.

Comment: Agreed. I was searching for the wrong terms (three dots instead of ellipsis).

Comment: to be fair it is a shame people use the term ellipsis. i can't imagine anyone discovering it other than finding out what 'three dots' can also be called. a classic case of unrequired jargon.